# How do you allow <style> tags in redactor v9.2.1?

Tags: css, redactor

I'm using Redactor v9.2.1. I'm trying to allow my customers to use style tags in their CMS, but redactor strips them from the content.

When I add the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .red{color:red;}
</style>
```

redactor strips it to:

```
<p>
.red{color:red;}
</p>
```

I've made sure that deniedTags is not including 'style' in my settings object and I'm not using the allowedTags attribute since it conflicts with deniedTags.

Here is my settings object that I'm passing to the redactor init:

```
var settings = {
    deniedTags:[
        'html', 'head','link', 'body', 'meta', 'applet'
    ],
    observeLinks: true,
    iframe: true,
    convertVideoLinks: true
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-deniedTags

> Top-level HTML tags ('html', 'head', 'link', 'body', 'meta', '**style**',
>   'script', 'applet') will always be removed regardless of this setting,
>   unless wrapped in 'pre' tag (formatting option 'Code')

### Edit

So you can't add a `style` tag inside the editor, as I read in the docs.  Seems like you have these options:

1. Style individual tags outside the editor: You add the parent selector `.redactor-editor` and then the tag name. See http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/typography/
2. Add several `formattingAdd` options to let users pick up custom styles from the `formatting` dropdown:

   ```
   $('#redactor').redactor({
       formattingAdd: [
       {
           tag: 'p',
           title: 'Red Block',
           class: 'red-style'
       }
       ]
   }); 
   /**
    * The above would create a new formatting entry,
    * which you define with 2 css selectors:
    * one for the class of the entry, another for the dropdown entry
    *  
    * .red-style, .redactor-dropdown .redactor-formatting-red-style {
    *     color: red;
    * }
    */
   ```

Notice css selector rule for the dropdown, which is `.redactor-dropdown .redactor-formatting-YOUR_CSS_CLASSNAME`. This also is important:

> formattingAdd can only be applied to p, pre, blockquote and header
>   tags.

So you can't apply it to `<div>`. If you need block element, use `<p>`. Also, if you need inline, you *CAN* use `<span>`... it works, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4df10vj/1/

Comment: how about link (a tag) ? i need to change style of link for example text-decoration:none. i can't do it via span tag

Comment: See first item link, follow it and there will be styles at the bottom, try .redactor-editor a